# this.form is null in my Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that will not submit:

```
<% form_for :venue, :html => { :id => "create_venue_form" } do |f| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'venues/venue_form_fields', :locals => { :f => f } %>
    <%= submit_to_remote    'add_venue_button', 
                            'Save Venue',
                            { 
                              :url => add_venue_path(@user.id),
                              :before => "alert(this.form);",
                              :html => {
                                 :id => "add_venue_button"
                              },
                              :update => "venue_select"
                            }
    %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this.form is null when prototype goes to serialize the form.  I have put the alert statement in other forms and this.form popped up to be an HTML form element, so I know it should not be evaluating to null.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: what does the rendered html look like?

Comment: hmmmm...no form tag is being generated...not sure why though.  maybe because it is nested in another form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create nested forms in HTML. You can put that nested form in a div and use [serializeElements](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serializeElements) to serialize all inputs within that div.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an AJAX update, which is how it appears, you should look at  [`remote_form_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_form_for)

Peer